# Cannot install openssl-dev for docker ruby alpine

Tags: ruby, linux, postgresql, docker, openssl

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base tzdata postgresql-dev postgresql-client

# throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock 

RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

ENV APP_PATH /app

RUN mkdir -p $APP_PATH 
WORKDIR $APP_PATH 
COPY Gemfile $APP_PATH 
COPY Gemfile.lock $APP_PATH 
RUN bundle install 
COPY . $APP_PATH

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I notice installing `postgresql-dev` will cause installing `openssl-dev`.

Anyway, run `docker-compose up` will output

```
$ docker-compose up
Building sidekiq
Step 1/12 : FROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine
 ---> 6ddb199f039f
Step 2/12 : RUN apk add --no-cache build-base tzdata postgresql-dev postgresql-client bash
 ---> Running in 386a4486295f
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/28) Upgrading libcrypto1.1 (1.1.1c-r0 -> 1.1.1d-r2)
(2/28) Upgrading libssl1.1 (1.1.1c-r0 -> 1.1.1d-r2)
(3/28) Installing bash (5.0.0-r0)
Executing bash-5.0.0-r0.post-install
(4/28) Installing binutils (2.32-r0)
(5/28) Installing libmagic (5.37-r1)
(6/28) Installing file (5.37-r1)
(7/28) Installing isl (0.18-r0)
(8/28) Installing libgomp (8.3.0-r0)
(9/28) Installing libatomic (8.3.0-r0)
(10/28) Installing mpfr3 (3.1.5-r1)
(11/28) Installing mpc1 (1.1.0-r0)
(12/28) Installing gcc (8.3.0-r0)
(13/28) Installing musl-dev (1.1.22-r3)
(14/28) Installing libc-dev (0.7.1-r0)
(15/28) Installing g++ (8.3.0-r0)
(16/28) Installing make (4.2.1-r2)
(17/28) Installing fortify-headers (1.1-r0)
(18/28) Installing build-base (0.5-r1)
(19/28) Installing libedit (20190324.3.1-r0)
(20/28) Installing db (5.3.28-r1)
(21/28) Installing libsasl (2.1.27-r4)
(22/28) Installing libldap (2.4.48-r0)
(23/28) Installing libpq (11.6-r0)
(24/28) Installing postgresql-client (11.6-r0)
(25/28) Installing openssl-dev (1.1.1d-r2)
```

in ubuntu, it is forever frozen for step `(25/28) Installing openssl-dev (1.1.1d-r2)`.

In mac, it shows

```
(25/27) Installing postgresql-libs (11.6-r0)
ERROR: Failed to create usr/lib/libssl.a: No error information
ERROR: openssl-dev-1.1.1d-r2: BAD signature
```

Is there anything wrong? Also, how can I get a bit more detailed info/log why it cannot install `openssl-dev`?

Comment: `apk add --verbose ...`

Comment: `RUN apk add --verbose build-base tzdata postgresql-dev postgresql-client` does not work

Comment: "does not work" is not useful diagnostic information. _What_ doesn't work? What output do you get? How does it differ from what you got previously? Regardless, I'm unable to reproduce this issue using docker-machine and VirtualBox on macOS Catalina. It successfully builds every time and installs the same version. (`openssl-dev (1.1.1d-r2)`)

Comment: @anothermh, thanks very much for your update. I've updated my original post a bit about error output. The tricky thing is in Ubuntu, it is just freezing at installing openssl-dev. In mac, it outputs  `ERROR: Failed to create usr/lib/libssl.a: No error information, openssl-dev-1.1.1d-r2: BAD signature`. You are very right. It is an old config. Previously it has no issue. No idea why it does not work now.

Comment: You're doing everything in Docker; your host OS doesn't matter. Again, I can't replicate this. I recommend you delete your existing Docker images and retry fresh.

Comment: ok, I got the reason. I tried diff os, including mac/ubuntu/win 10, at diff computers. But all have the same issues. Thanks for @anothermh's reminder. I tried one of my free oracle vps, which has only 1G ram but installing the above Dockerfile without any issue. That is strongly hinting the reason may be the internet connection. I switched from internet from home wifi to mobile internet. All issues are gone. May be one internet route from my ISP to docker source is broken. Thanks very much for your helps, anothermh

Comment: I am facing this problem and my internet does seem ok. And interesting thing is, the build is successful in mac os while it freezes in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @anothermh It seems `-v, --verbose` is a global option for `apk` (according to `apk -h -v`) hence you should place it before the `add` and can be repeated to be more verbose => `apk -vv add postgresql-libs`